# AFHTTPRequestOperation with SSL Pinning not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl, pinning

I am using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` for my iPhone app (Objective-C). I need to enable the `SSL` pinning for my app.

However, no matter the certificate that I have included in my app bundle is the correct or wrong, calling to my API is always successful.

Should the calling of my server API be failed if the certificate that I pinned in my app is the wrong cert?

This is the code that I have in the app:

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure{
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = self.responseSerializer;
    operation.shouldUseCredentialStorage = self.shouldUseCredentialStorage;
    operation.credential = self.credential;
    //operation.securityPolicy = self.securityPolicy;

    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
    NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wrong_cert" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO];
    [securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:YES];
    [securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:@[certData]];
    [operation setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    operation.completionQueue = self.completionQueue;
    operation.completionGroup = self.completionGroup;

    return operation;

}
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i implemented SSL Pinning succesfully with AFNetworking. Please ensure your certificate is valid before doing test. Look below code snippet.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager sharedManager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *post = [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

        [delegate requestCompleted:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        if([error.domain isEqualToString:@"NSURLErrorDomain"] && error.code == -1012){
            //SSL Pinning request failed

        } else if (!operation.cancelled) {

        }
    }];

    [post start];
```